# iOS and timer app: is there a way to prevent screensaver to start?

Tags: ios, timer, screen, screensaver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I prevent the iPhone screen from dimming or turning off while my application is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125619/how-do-i-prevent-the-iphone-screen-from-dimming-or-turning-off-while-my-applicat)

I am working on a timer app and was wondering if there is a way to tell iOS not to start the screensaver when the app is idle (e.g. timer laying on the table).

I would also like to keep the screen brightness at maximum level.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For disabling the screensaver, try this:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

For adjusting the brightness of the screen (iOS5 and later **only,** previously there was no public API for this):

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:1.0];
```